AIX 7.3 Error "runtime definition of the symbol was not found" when the method is define and built & linked without any problem
I get below error for one of the programs:
lib/pm_db_create
Could not load program pm_db_create:
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol _ZN10OTDSConfig11GetInstanceEv was referenced
from module /home/rahul/install/otos/lib/libauthzss.2.so(), but a runtime definition
of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol _ZN10OTDSConfig13IsOTDSEnabledEv was referenced
from module /home/rahul/install/otos/lib/libauthzss.2.so(), but a runtime definition
of the symbol was not found.
rtld: 0712-002 fatal error: exiting.
Below is the code snippet of the declarations for GetInstance() and IsOTDSEnabled() in OTDSConfig.h
Definitions in corresponding OTDSConfig.cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef OTDSCONFIG_H_
#define OTDSCONFIG_H_

#include <iostream>

class OTDSConfig
{
public:
static OTDSConfig * GetInstance();
void Clean();
std::string GetOTDSUrl();
bool IsOTDSEnabled();

private:
OTDSConfig();
~OTDSConfig();
std::string m_otds_Url;
};

#endif

Below is the code snippet for definition of GetInstance() and IsOTDSEnabled()
OTDSConfig * OTDSConfig::GetInstance()
{
    if (_otdsConfig == NULL) {
        _otdsConfig = new OTDSConfig();
    }

    return _otdsConfig;
}

bool OTDSConfig::IsOTDSEnabled()
{
    if (m_otds_Url.empty() || m_clientId.empty() || m_secret.empty() || m_partition.empty())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

Below is the code snippet of the call made to GetInstance() and IsOTDSEnabled() in otdsop.cpp
#include "otdsop.h"
#include "OTDSConnector.h"
#include "OTDSConnectorWrapper.h"
#include "OTDSConfig.h"

int SetUserInPM()
{
if (OTDSConfig::GetInstance()->IsOTDSEnabled() == false)
{
debug_log_message("OTDS not configured");
log_message(OTDS_NOT_CONFIGURED);
return -1;
}

return 0;
}

Below commands are used to create the libraries libotds.1.so & libauthzss.2.so
g++ -maix64 -shared -o libotds.1.so cat libotds.1.lst -Wl,-b64 -Wl,-G -Wl,-bnoentry -Wl,-bnolibpath -Wl,-bnoipath -Wl,-bexpall -Wl,-bE:libotds.1.exp -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/master/exports/lib -lcurl -lC -lc_r
g++ -maix64 -shared -o libauthzss.2.so cat libauthzss.2.lst -Wl,-brtl -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/master/exports/lib -lotds.1 -Wl,-b64 -Wl,-G -Wl,-bnoentry -Wl,-bnolibpath -Wl,-bnoipath -Wl,-bexpall -Wl,-bE:libauthzss.2.exp -L/eng/otbuild/aix73/os/master/exports/lib -llicense -lc_r
LIBPATH variable shows correct value
Compiled with gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

OTDSConfig * OTDSConfig::GetInstance()
{
if (_otdsConfig == NULL) {
_otdsConfig = new OTDSConfig();
}
    return _otdsConfig;

}
bool OTDSConfig::IsOTDSEnabled()
{
if (m_otds_Url.empty() || m_clientId.empty() || m_secret.empty() || m_partition.empty())
return false;
else
return true;
}

GetInstance & IsOTDSEnabled are couple of examples. Same error is seen for few more methods. All these methods are defined but runtime show error. If

Please provide a [mcve] (edit the original post, don't insert code into comments).

Edited the original post. Added code for GetInstance() & IsOTDSEnabled()

You don't seem to understand what an [mcve] is, so I show you an example: git clone https://github.com/lzsiga/linktest.git; cd linktest/without_libtool; make main_so; ./main_so
